# docker in gitlab pipeline cant access compose file on host machine

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

Im using the following .gitlab-ci.yml :

```
stages:
    - build

docker-build:
  # Use the official docker image.
  image:
    name: docker:latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  script:
    - docker-compose -f compose_testfile.yaml down
  ...(and so on)
```

But I get the error:

/builds/testaccount/testproject/compose_testfile.yaml: no such file or directory

the compose-file is on the machine where the gitlab-runner is installed on, how can I access this file from the .gitlab-ci.yml in docker-build ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the compose config file to the repository, just as you do with  the gitlab pipeline config.